# Sql join multiple tables and get data

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Hello I need to retrieve data from a database which has multiple tables and I don't know how to write the join. I have these tables: 
`Users:
 -userid
 -username
 -userpassword
 -fullname`

`Courses:
 -courseid
 -coursename`

and
`Enrolled:
 -userid
 -courseid
 -grade`

I need to retrieve for a user all his grades.
I am really stuck on joining all the tables.
Please help

Comment: what happened when you googled for "joins" (and your database software's name)? what did you try from that and why were the results unsatisfactory to you? Can you give us sample data of what you'd like and what you got instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read on the `JOIN` syntax: `http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp`

```
SELECT
    u.userid,
    u.username,
    u.fullname,
    c.courseid
    c.coursename,
    e.grade
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Enrolled e
    ON e.userid = u.userid
LEFT JOIN Courses c
    ON c.courseid = e.courseid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select U.ID,U.username,E.grade from Users U
left join  Enrolled E
on U.userid=E.userid
```